# Calling function from iframe not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to call a parent function from inside of an iframe to remove the container div however it seems to be failing and I am unsure why. I am wondering if it is because the iframe loads before the parent window and so the function is not yet defined.

Here is my parents html:

```
<div align="center" id="review-embed-container" style="position: relative;">
    <iframe frameBorder="0" id="review-embed-iframe" src="http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/review/Review-Embed.php?code=1&prod_name=test" scrolling="no" width="100%">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And the parents jQuery:

```
function InjectIframeReview() {
        $("#review-embed-container").hide();
};
```

Now inside the Iframe page I have php that checks to see if reviews are placed, if there are no reviews it calls this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.InjectIframeReview();
</script>
```

I can't seem to find out why the function is not firing correctly, you can see the full website it is loaded on here:

Websites JQuery (function is on line 387):
http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/acatalog/custom.js

A page that has no reviews (iframe on line 902 of source code):
http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/acatalog/8ft_Skyhigh_Trampoline_and_Safety_Enclosure.html

The Iframe that gets loaded (no review for product so just has javascript):
http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/review/Review-Embed.php?code=3271d&prod_name=8ft%20Skyhigh%20Trampoline%20and%20Safety%20Enclosure

A page that has a review:
http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/acatalog/8ft_Fun_Pink_Trampoline.html

The Iframe that gets loaded (has review so does not use javascript):
http://www.trampolinesshop.co.uk/review/Review-Embed.php?code=3269&prod_name=8ft%20Skyhigh%20Pink%20Trampoline%20and%20Safety%20Enclosure

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html May be you are using chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chrome security](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html) May be you are using chrome. If you are using chrome this problem may affect only in local server because your chrome check your domain. But when you upload it on  it will work because that time your domain will same as iframe domain. So now just check it on other browsers.
This issue will solved when you upload it into live. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286981/jquery-iframe-onload-event-is-not-executing-on-google-chrome)

Comment: This was the problem, I was using chrome. Thanks for the help and pointers.